# Make $* check for string

Tags: makefile

I am trying to check if $* matches hello . But the following is not working

```
 build: build-hello

 build-%:
 ifeq ($*, hello)
   echo Hello
 else
   echo World
 endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions in the `ifeq`'s are processed at makefile read time -- when `$*` is still blank.   There's a couple of workarounds to this:  First, you could do a `build-hello:` rule, which would override the `build-%` rule for `build-hello`.   If, on the other hand you wanted to minimize rules, you could use the `$(if)` function as so:

```
build-%:
   @echo $(if $(filter $*,hello),Hello,World)
```

Or, you could just use shell logic to accomplish this as well.